# How to save changes/ update an ArrayList<Objects> in onPause (Android)?

Tags: android, arraylist

Please bear with me since I am completely new to Android programming. This a project that I had to do for my computer science class at school.I have been reading the developer guides on the site and understand that in order for changes to be saved in an Activity, I would have to call the onPause() method.

My program is simply a recipe library that allows the user to add entries and remove/edit them. I created an ArrayList to store the recipes and used List> with a listView and SimpleAdapter to display the collection. I read about the SavedPreferences, but it seems that SavedPreferences would best be used when storing primitives, not Objects. Some Google searches told me that some people recommended using onSaveInstanceState(). However, that is not always called and shouldn't be used to save changes. That being said, how would I save my ArrayList so that when I exit, the changes are saved (i.e. when I delete an item, exit, and come back, the item stays deleted)?

Comment: Here is [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). And here are [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here If you are going to finish the application after doing any operation then there is not way to save the ArrayList. it's better to use the SQLite database to store the data and perform the operations as you mentioned.

Since local variable will always get cleared once you exit the application best approach is to use the SQL only.